# What are Google Webfonts alternatives to Novecento Wide?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts, sans-serif

Are there any Google web fonts similar to Novecento Wide?

[image]

Comment: You can get most weights of Novecento Wide for free. Obviously you would need to self-host the fonts but it's an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a Helvetica Derivation. The closest Google Web font to Novencento would be the font named Montserrat.

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Montserrat

[image]

Comment: +1 because it is a good fit, it certainly isn't a Helvetica derivative though.

Comment: @Cai, I disagree with you, this font was created based on posters from the 1950's in Monteserrat (Caribbean). In the creators own words this "typeface... rescues the beauty of urban typography from the first half of the twentieth century". Monteserrat, a British owned territory utilized typography aesthetics from France, Spain, England, and you guessed it, Switzerland! You can see the similarities between the two fonts and how the designerused Helvetica as a base to work from. A beautiful font, and a Helvetica derivative. montserrat.zkysky.com.ar/